# How can I dynamically change the number of variable a netlogo agent has?

Tags: netlogo

I have a model where agents or patches have an opinion of two things A and B:

```
patches-own[
OpinionA
OpinionB
]
```

And then the values for these are set randomly at the start.

How could I change this so that there could be more than two things? In fact, I'd like to have that number set by a slider. How can I dynamically change the number of variable an agent or patch has?

Answer (score 4):

I don`t think it is possible to create new agent-variables on the fly, but you could instead use just one agent-variable and use a list to store multiple Opinions. You could define the length of that list by a slider and randomly set each position of the list to a specific Opinion.
For example if you want the patches to have x different Opinions (defined by the slider x) which have either "a", "b" or "c" you could do that as follows:

```
patches-own[
  opinion
]

to setup
  ... (some setup procedure stuff)

  let opinion-options (list "a" "b" "c")

  ask patches[
    set opinion n-values x [one-of opinion-options]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `table` extension:

```
extensions [table]

patches-own[
  opinions
]

to setup
  ask patches [
    set opinions table:make
  ]
  ; ... 
end
```

Set opinions with "key-value" pair where key is the opinion type and value  the actual attitude. For example:

```
ask n-of 5 patches [
  table:put opinions "favorite-color" "blue"
  table:put opinions "food" "pizza"
]
```

You can set different number of opinions to another group of patches:

```
ask n-of 5 patches [
  table:put opinions "favorite-color" "red"
  table:put opinions "food" "chocolate"
  table:put opinions "age" 5
]
```

Show opinion about food (for patches with opinion about food):

```
ask patches with [ table:has-key? opinions "food" ] 
  [ show table:get opinions "food ]
```

#### Dynamic version

Example, how to set `n` opinions randomly:

```
 let number-of-opinions 3
 ask n-of 5 patches [
   (foreach n-values 3 [?] n-values 3 [random 10]
     [ table:put opinions ?1 ?2 ])
 ]
```

Here 3 opinions (named 0, 1 and 2) have been set with random numbers (from 0 to 9). To check opinion 1 use:

```
ask patches with [ table:has-key? opinions 1 ] 
  [ show table:get opinions 1 ]
```

Note that `with` checks if specific opinion type is set before asking for value.

See also table examples in [documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html).

Comment: I would not suggesting resort to tables without determining first that lists aren't enough to solve the problem. So I would suggest trying Tyr's solution first.